# Python module install fail

Tags: python, cryptography, aes

```
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\justi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da2ionqs\\pycrypto_673a5aa24bcd423c8255532c2be5ffbf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\justi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da2ionqs\\pycrypto_673a5aa24bcd423c8255532c2be5ffbf\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tcjonqxh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I do not want to install vscode or vs. This is be ran on machines that do not have these things installed. Does anyone know how to fix this without pycrypto commiting die or installing vs? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to build `pycrypto` - the last release was in 2013, it's chock full of security holes! Use [`cryptography`](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) instead.

Comment: Just because of the program I'm using, I can't to cryptography. Sad.